# SQL sub query not fetching right data

Tags: sql

I  just started some programming classes and I was writing CRUD operations to fetch some data. everytime the below sub query is returning max end date from contract table however it should return the date which matches all the relationships in 3 different table. looks like sub query is ignoring where clause. I do not have much experience in sub query looks like I am doing some blunder mistake please help. guys I am almost done now I need to figure out how can I use max function in subquery something like this ....        AND ( MAX(employee.DT_START) <= (SELECT Max(A.DT_END) 
                                   FROM   contract A........

please suggest how can I use max function for employee.DT_START

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.FIRST_NAME 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  employee.ID_EMP = 1 
       AND ( employee.DT_START <= (SELECT Max(A.DT_END) 
                                   FROM   contract A, 
                                          salary E, 
                                          department D 
                                   WHERE  A.ID_PRSN = E.ID_PRSN 
                                          AND A.ID_DEPT = D.ID_DEPT) );
```

Comment: We need table definitions and an explanation of what "it should return the date which matches all the relationships in 3 different table" means

Comment: Is `ID_EMP` the primary key in table `EMPLOYEE`?

Comment: Subqueries are usually much better accomplished with a proper `JOIN`, especially in the `WHERE` clause. Also, pretty please don't use old comma-syntax `JOIN`s. They are 1) way out of date 2) can cause significant query data bloat and 3) can easily return unexpected results.

Comment: in the contract table there is max date of 11/30/18, however if relationship matches of 3 tables then it should have returned 11/20/17 but right now its only returning max date of 11/30/18.

Comment: Also, what flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might be missing a link between the outmost `employee` table and the correlated subquery (which isn't correlated now, because there is no clause linking the employee with contract, salary nor department). This is pure speculation tho.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  If you are choosing based on one `id_emp`, why are you using `select distinct`.  There are lots of other issues with the query.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        select distinct emp.FIRST_NAME from
                            (                                     
                            SELECT FIRST_NAME, max(DT_START) as DT_START
                            FROM   employee 
                            WHERE  ID_EMP = 1 
                            group by FIRST_NAME
                            ) emp,
                            (SELECT Max(A.DT_END) as DT_END 
                                           FROM   contract A, 
                                                  salary E, 
                                                  department D 
                                           WHERE  A.ID_PRSN = E.ID_PRSN 
                                                  AND A.ID_DEPT = D.ID_DEPT
                            ) sal
        where emp.DT_START <= sal.DT_END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JOIN if you want to get values based on relationships in 3 different tables.

Comment: do you have any mock-up for joining 3 different tables